# What does this notation mean? (ERD)

Tags: database, database-design, erd

I have troubles understanding the notation on the model I was given.
I assume it means 1-n (0 included) but I do not understand why - any medication should have a dose, in addition, the keys are not nullable. So how could there be 0?

[image]

Comment: The diagram means that every Medicament is required to have a corresponding Dose but it is possible to have a Dose without any corresponding Medicament.

Comment: What @sqlvogel said, plus that many Medicaments may have the same Dose.  This is called "Crow's-Foot Notation", and while it's not the prettiest, many experts prefer it because (IMHO) it provides the most information concisely.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thanks, yes, but sense would have a Dose without a Medicament? PS: Would it not better to use UML data profile for modeling databases, is there any difference_

Answer (score 2):

The notation is Crow's foot notation for Entity Relationship modeling (this is concerned with Entity name, Lines and boxes and names on relationships which are absent here only).

Each tool has it own way of representing some of the aspects of a data model. For example some tools use dashed/dotted lines to represent *non-identifying relationship* (that is the FK is allowed to change).

The diagram (boxes and lines) tells us:

R1- Each [Dose] is administrated as 0,1,...,N [Medicament(s)]

R2- Each [Medicament] Must have 1 prescribed [Dose]

- NN means Not Null (this is tool dependent)
- The primary key for Dose is ID
- The primary key for Medicament is both [ID] and [ID Dose] (a FK from Dose).

*You are correct to assume that the diagram is inconsistent. (NN) Not Nullable indicates Mandatory relationship at the [Medicament] end.* Hence the (0) or little circle should not be there.

I have guessed what the relationships are in the above text, I could be wrong. That is why the data modeler should have clarified what they mean exactly otherwise the relationship could be interpreted wrong.

Here is a similar diagram using MySQL Workbench ERD Tool - No little circles or zero is shown with either types of lines:

[image]

**Edit/Correction**

Not being familiar with the specific tool used to represent the diagram, I assumed that both columns are part of a compound key for the child table. However, as the comment below by @KhDonen indicates, this does not have to be the case. Maybe the tool designate FK with a "key" symbol/icon even if it is not part of the PK. In which case, there would only be 1 key on each table and the diagram will be consistent.

Comment: Why do you think that the primary key for Medicament is both ID and IDDose? There is just one PK as I can see. Also for the consistency, why would it be inconsistent? The PK in Dose is not-null, so it can exist alone.

Comment: I say that PK is composite because the diagram shows 2 key symbols (to the left of each column in Medicament entity). The inconsistency exists since the DoseID is specified as part of the PK yet, the line is shown as a dashed line. I hope this is a bit more clear.

Comment: Thanks, but I still do not get the PK part - if you check the Dose entity, it has just one primary key, denoted by PK. The Medicament has one PK and one FK..also just one PK. SO the line should be solid? I thought that this is only when PK is FK at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your remark, you are probably correct. I made an edit to the answer.

Comment: Thank you - I want to know the answer as well as the OP, I just wanted to be sure.I still believe that there is no sense in having Dose alone.